# DataTable, how to skip a line after spesific row before export as PDF?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, export

```
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jszip-3.10.1/dt-1.13.5/b-2.4.1/b-colvis-2.4.1/b-html5-2.4.1/b-print-2.4.1/fh-3.4.0/kt-2.10.0/r-2.5.0/rg-1.4.0/sl-1.7.0/sr-1.3.0/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.2.7/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.2.7/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/jszip-3.10.1/dt-1.13.5/b-2.4.1/b-colvis-2.4.1/b-html5-2.4.1/b-print-2.4.1/fh-3.4.0/kt-2.10.0/r-2.5.0/rg-1.4.0/sl-1.7.0/sr-1.3.0/datatables.min.js"></script>
```

My datatable preferences like this:

```
    $('#savedTable').DataTable({
        language: {
            url: '//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.13.5/i18n/tr.json',
        },
        responsive: true,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o mr-2"></i> EXCEL'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    pageSize: 'LEGAL',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o mr-2"></i>PDF'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'colvis',
                    text: '<i class="fa fa-eye mr-2"></i> Sütunlar'
                }
            ],
        searching: true,
        select: true,
      });
```

I have 12 columns on my table. I want to skip a line after 6th column before export as PDF because It's overflowing from the screen. Maybe someone has better idea for this.

I search for it and see that there is 'customizeExport' or something like that but I do not know how to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to hide unnecessary lines like following.

```
<style>
    @media print{
      .d-none{
        display: none
      }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: But I do not want to hide columns.